# Выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу или типу перечисления без области видимости

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь подключить авторизацию с форума. Получаю ошибку: «*выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу или типу перечисления без области видимости*».

```
static char errorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
static string buffers;
CURL* curl = nullptr;
CURLcode result;
curl = curl_easy_init();

static char out_name[32],
out_pass[32];
if (curl)
{
    string req = ("login=") + out_name + ("&register=0&password=")+ out_pass + "&remember=0&cookie_check=0&redirect=/&_xfToken=";

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, ("xen_load"));
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, ("http://site.ru/login/login/"));
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, req.c_str());

    result = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    long response_code = 0;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static char out_name[32],
out_pass[32];

string req = ("login=") + out_name + ("&register=0&password=")+ out_pass + "&remember=0&cookie_check=0&redirect=/&_xfToken=";
```

Вы пытаетесь просуммировать два массива и три указателя. Для конкатенации строк используйте `std::string`

```
string req = std::string("login=") + out_name + ("&register=0&password=")+ out_pass + "&remember=0&cookie_check=0&redirect=/&_xfToken=";
```